# Problem with overloaded member function in c++

Tags: c++

I have a problem with constructors and member functions. When I try to compile the program, it shows: error:

> ‘int Vehicle::range()’ cannot be overloaded.

What should I do in this case ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Vehicle{
public:
    int passengers;
    int fuelcap;
    int mpg;
    int range();
    Vehicle(int p,int f,int m);
    int range();
};

Vehicle::Vehicle(int p,int f,int m){
    passengers=p;
    fuelcap=f;
    mpg=m;
}

int Vehicle::range(){
    return mpg*fuelcap;
}
```

I haven't shown the main function because the problem must be here.

I expect the output of 336 and 168.

Comment: `int range();` twice in the same class looks questionable.

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring `Vehicle::range` twice inside the class body:

```
int range();
Vehicle(int p,int f,int m);
int range();
```

Remove the second one and it should work.

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/w_lHLy)'s a minimal example, replicating the error you're getting.

Comment: Another suggestion: Update the compiler. g++ 9.3's error message for this is brutally explicit.